# Relation between Gitlab Chat and Mattermost

Tags: gitlab, mattermost

I saw `chat` tab in Gitlab, and it shows no active users. 
To enable the chat I found this [forum](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/how-to-enable-chat/9254) where they mentioned about `mattermost`.

What is the relation between `chat` and `mattermost`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gitlab ships with the Team Edition of Mattermost. There are instructions for setting Mattermost up on your Gitlab server here: https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/gitlab-mattermost/.